Spark consumer couldn't find kafka topic partition when running using docker
When I submit my spark application that connects to kafka broker it execute the kafka query but doesn't return anything into the console. It fails to find the topic partition.
Here is the logs on my console:
QUERYYYYYYYYY DOOONE Streaming query started 
24/05/25 11:10:39 WARN AdminClientConfig: These configurations '[key.deserializer, value.deserializer, enable.auto.commit, max.poll.records, auto.offset.reset]' were supplied but are not used yet. 

24/05/25 11:13:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.18.0.4 executor 0): org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition captions-0 could be determined

also when I run my spark application using my local config(because I have already installed and configured spark on my local machine) it works fine and spark consume data from the kafka topic as expected.
here is my spark application code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

def createSparkSession():
    s_conn = None

    try:
        s_conn = SparkSession.builder.appName("pfa Spark")\
            .master("spark://localhost:7077")\
            .config('spark.jars.packages',"org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.1") \
            .getOrCreate()
        s_conn.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")
        # s_conn.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
        print("GOAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAL\nSpark Session Created")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"TFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU ---> {e}")

    return s_conn

def createKafkaSession(spark_session):
    spark_df = None
    try:
        spark_df = spark_session.readStream \
            .format('kafka') \
            .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'localhost:9092') \
            .option('subscribe', 'captions') \
            .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest')\
            .load()
        print("kafka dataframe created successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"kafka dataframe could not be created because: {e}")

    return spark_df


if __name__ == '__main__':

    s_conn = createSparkSession()
    print(s_conn)

    if s_conn:
        print("Spark session is active")
        k_conn = createKafkaSession(s_conn)
        
        if k_conn:
            print("Kafka connection is active")

            k_conn = k_conn.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
            print("data is read!!!!!!!!!!!!!")

            processed_df = k_conn.withColumn("value", expr("upper(value)"))  # Example transformation
            print("Data is processed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
            # Write the stream to the console (or any other sink)
            query = processed_df.writeStream \
                .outputMode("update") \
                .format("console") \
                .start()
                # .trigger(processingTime='30 seconds')\
            print("QUERYYYYYYYYY DOOONE\nStreaming query started")
            query.awaitTermination()
            print("Query finished")
        else:
            print("Failed to create Kafka connection")
    else:
        print("Failed to create Spark session")

And here is my docker-compose.yml file:
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
      image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.4.0
      hostname: zookeeper
      container_name: zookeeper
      ports:
        - "2181:2181"
      environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      healthcheck:
        test: ['CMD', 'bash', '-c', "echo 'ruok' | nc localhost 2181"]
        interval: 10s
        timeout: 5s
        retries: 5
      networks:
        - confluent

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.4.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      zookeeper:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "bash", "-c", 'nc -z localhost 9092' ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.4.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8081/" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.4.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      broker:
        condition: service_healthy
      schema-registry:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      CONFLIENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      PORT: 9021
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9021/health" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
  #Spark Master
  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
      - "7077:7077"
    networks:
      - confluent

  #Spark worker
  spark-worker:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://spark-master:7077
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    environment:
      SPARK_MODE: worker
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
      SPARK_MASTER_URL: spark://spark-master:7077
    networks:
      - confluent
networks:
  confluent:

I have tried changing the option of the bootstrap_servers in the kafka session configuration into broker but it didn't work eite=her.
.option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'broker:9092')


You've set PLAINTEXT://broker:29092 as the advertised listener. That's the address Spark should connect to (port included).
You should also set this on the broker to ensure port 29092 is used
KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://:9092 


thanks for reply!
But  I have added this env var into my kafka broker configuration but still getting the same problem!
Is there anything related to the problem of the consumer when it can't find the topic partitions!?
